# html5 - how to set an box on the right side of my container

Tags: css, html

Hello my name is kryparn and I need help to add a box on the right side of the container like this!

[image].

index.html

```
    <body>
<div id="rightBox">
    Test2
</div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <center><img src="http://log.guchua.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/fireball-resized-image-960x200.jpg" /><center>
            <div id="nav">
                <div id="nav_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img width="16" height="16" src="img/home-md.png" /> Hem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nyhetsarkiv</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Administratörer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spelsektion <img src="img/dropdown-arrow.png"/></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Server 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Server 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Server 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="first">
                hej
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle: [Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/52gLw96v/)

Comment: You might need to explain the box on the right a bit better? Is it for adverts and it can disappear if the persons screen width is to small. Is it for content and has to be visible all the time? if it needs to be there all the time then put it inside the wrapper div. if its for adverts then maybe a position absolute or fixed might work better with jquery or css hiding the div depending on the screen width

Comment: i gona have content in it and its gona be visible all the time and i don't know how to do it

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/52gLw96v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper with a clearfix to your content, both the main and the sidebar to the right. More on clearfixing here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ make sure your wrapper has enough width to contain both (your #nav and your #container are set to 960px, and your #right has to be a certain width)

Make your #right float:right and your #wrapper float:left; Set their widths and it should work.

For the sake of responsiveness I recommend using percents instead of pixels for the widths of major layout elements